# Why does assigning a color to the background of my ListView element not cover the entire ListView background, while assigning a drawable does?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I have a `ListView` that sits on the left side of a tablet-size screen.  My goal was to give it a solid background with a border on the right, then apply an overlapping background on the list element to break that border so that it appears to be a part of the view on the right.

---

### The ListView Background

I achieved the right border using a `<layer-list>` drawable [as suggested by Emile in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4313329/780075):

rightborder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

...and here's the ListView definition for good measure:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/msglist"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rightborder"
    android:paddingRight="0dip">
</ListView>
<!-- I added the android:paddingRight after reading something 
about shape drawables and padding, don't think it actually
did anything. -->
```

---

### Attempting to override it with a color

In order to achieve the desired effect, I placed the following in the `getView` function of my adapter:

```
//If it's selected, highlight the background
if(position == mSelectedIndex)
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.light_gray);

else
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

However, using this method, **the black border of the `ListView`'s drawable remained visible, and only the white part of the background was replaced by gray.**  Here's a screen capture:

[image: Border showing through color background]

---

### Fixing it with a drawable

On a hunch, I replaced the color I was assigning with a `shape` drawable:

selectedmessage.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/light_gray" />
</shape>
```

getView snippet:

```
//If it's selected, highlight the background
if(position == mSelectedIndex)
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectedmessage);

else
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

This achieves the desired result, as shown below:

[image: Border no longer showing]

---

### The question:

Why does assigning a rectangle as the background for my `ListView` element cover the entire view, while assigning the color allows the black border to show through?  I'm happy it's working, but I'd like to know why Android is rendering the view this way so I can learn more about how Android renders Views.

### Other notes:

- I'm running the project in the stock Android 3.2 emulator, if that makes any
  difference.
- One clue may be that the `light_gray` color background seems to render darker than the `light_gray` `shape` resource.
- I doubt it makes a difference, but `light_gray` is:

  `<color name="light_gray">#FFCCCCCC</color>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
 convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.light_gray);
```

setBackgroundColor does not take a resource id : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29)

So your getting some incidental behaviour that isn't doing what your expecting.

You would have to do:

```
 convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29)

Comment: Ah, okay, based on that, looks like I was getting a dark color with an unexpected semi-transparent alpha value because it was trying to use the resource integer as a color, and the border showed through that.