# How to create a titled border in Android?

Tags: android, titled-border

has someone an idea how to create a titled border layout like in [swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)?

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view) site i found a trick to generate a rectangle between a object. Maybe this can help me to create such a titled border?

greetings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:color="#000000">
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TITLE!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And `@drawable/rectangle` is in a drawable `rectangle.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
<stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="#ffffff"/>  
</shape>
```

Comment: I see how this is quick, but how is it dirty? Isn't this what the <View> tag is for? I supposed you could also define a separate title layout and include it at the top using <include>

Comment: This could certainly be that separate layout.