# Border with title in Android?

Tags: android, border, shapes

We can use `shape` to create a simple border,for example I saw this code [here](http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/android-how-to-create-rounded-border-or-background/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But I need a border with a title like this image:

[image]

How I can do that?

Comment: is that image came from web form?

Comment: Do you want the border around the `Installation` text ? Is it a layout of your application ? If yes then please post the code of your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found a good code that helps me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636799/how-to-create-a-titled-border-in-android).I add code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:color="#000000">
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TITLE!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And @drawable/rectangle is in a drawable rectangle.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
<stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="#ffffff"/>  
</shape>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out the below code and create the xml file in your application's `res/drawable` folder and paste the below code:

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:shape="rectangle" >
> <corners android:radius="3dp" />
> <solid android:color="#00000000" />
> <stroke
>     android:width="2dp"
>     android:color="#1B455F" />
>   <padding android:left="5dp"
>     android:top="5dp"
>     android:right="5dp"
>     android:bottom="5dp"/>
> </shape>
> ```

You can change the border color according to your convenience by changing the stroke color.

Use the above xml as below: Here i have tried to set the border on the TextView.

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="@drawable/border"
>     android:text="@string/hello_world" />
> ```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: @Grishu Thank you,but it is not what I want.This is a simple border.I want a border with a place for it's title and it's title must be above the border.