# How to reset the style of an edittext?

Tags: android

I have an edit text which I validate. If the data entered does not corespond to the format, I set the background to red, when it coresponds I set it back to light gray, but the rectangle disappears. 
I was wondering if I could reset it's properties to their orignal values when the data entered has the correct format.
This is what i am doing now

```
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
if (name.getText().length() < 1)
{
    error = true;
    unit.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
else
{
    //instead of this line reset edittext properties
    unit.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by reset??

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the reactangle disappears"? So when setting it to RED all is fine but when setting it to LTGRAY the border around the box disappears?

Comment: yes the border disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
editText.setText("");
```

Comment: i want to reset the layout not the text, reverting the background to it's original style

Comment: Okay,  final Drawable oldBackground = activity.findViewById(id).getBackground();if(correct){ text.setBackgroundDrawable(oldBackground);}

Comment: the border still disappears

Comment: the only thing (i think) to do is to draw the border

Comment: Thank you for the sign, but can you explain to us which was the solution?@Liviu

Comment: you gave me the ideea to draw the border and i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view

Answer (score 1):

You can use PorterDuff instead - it has a clear method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html.

To set the color:

```
name.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

To remove the color:

```
name.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `setError()` method, which displays an error message above the `EditText` and removes it automatically when the contents of the `EditText` change. This is a standard way to show the user that the validation has failed.

Comment: i am required to set the background to red, and then revert to the original edittext, my problem is that the border disappears when changing back to the original background color

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the `EditText` background so you are overriding android's default background.
you need to manually change it to some other background.
you can save it by Using the `getBackground()` method in `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the status of the editText before to change it, and restore when you need:

```
private Drawable originalDrawable;

EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
if (name.getText().length() < 1) {
    if (originalDrawable == null) {
        originalDrawable = unit.getBackground();
    }
    error = true;
    unit.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
else {
    //reset editText 
    text.setBackgroundDrawable(originalDrawable);
}
```