# How to show only top and bottom border

Tags: android, layer-list, android-shape

This is my XML code which works fine, the only problem is it's showing border on all four sides while I want only to show border on the top and on the bottom only. How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#B1BCBE"
    />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip"
    />

</shape>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view)

Answer (score 48):

Try the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> 
    </shape>
  </item>   
    <item android:bottom="5dp"  android:top="5dp" >  
     // add android:right="5dp" and android:left="5dp" for border on left and right
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
      <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
   </item>    
 </layer-list>
```

[image]

Edit:

Modify the below according to your requirements by changing the color, stroke width and padding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="5dip"
        android:color="#B1BCBE"
    />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip"
    />
    </shape>
  </item>   
    <item android:bottom="5dp"  android:top="5dp" >  
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
      <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
   </item>    
 </layer-list>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted red on top and blue on bottom? I want something like this: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FI3EGIqLOc4/VkNs8YtLSGI/AAAAAAAAb6w/yEGC_F3zP9o/s1600/AndroidLayerDrawableProgrammatically.png around the layout... any way to do it without code and through XML?

Comment: why the layer-list ?

Answer (score 16):

use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <!-- Describes the line -->
    <item android:top="-1dp" android:bottom="-1dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>   
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: try with margin. removing pading left and right and give < android:marginLeft = "-3dip">

Comment: <item android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="-1dp" android:right="-1dp">

Comment: This looks too good to be true. Are there any known issues? For example on some devices does the invisible strokes stutter due to the fractional dp differences?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<padding
    android:bottom="0dip"
    android:left="-1dip"
    android:right="-1dip"
    android:top="0dip" 
/>
```

Comment: increase the negative padding or margin. :)

Answer (score 2):

Its best not to mention the height and width attributes in layer-list as height and width attributes of item is supported only from API 23.

You can use below Drawable that worked below Android 4.0 and above 5.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue_light" />  <!-- this is stroke color-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_blue" />  <!-- this is main color-->
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#cccccc"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#efefef"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: color sceme change now my background color is ffff ur is change