# Only Top Border in a Shape

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I want show only top border in android rectangle shape. I have searched lot for do it but does not found any working solution for it. My current shape code is like below

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#391901"
        android:endColor="#2f1502"
        android:startColor="#411d02" />

</shape>
```

I want only border on top side of shape. Let me know if any one have idea to do it.

[image]
Example Image

Comment: can you show an expected preview?

Comment: @AswinPAshok I have added it

Comment: i think you should use a ninepatch drawable. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: You can use a layer-list drawable like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719206/how-to-show-only-top-and-bottom-border). I flagged your question as "duplicate" because understanding the answers to the other question will enable you to solve your problem