# Android add border to edit text programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, background-color

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view) example and tried to add it to my edit text programmatically like `editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_back);`, but it does not work. How can I accomplish this? Any suggestions or ideas?

**EDIT** The editText is defined programmatically as well.

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this.getApplicationContext());
```

I added this to a table row

**TRIED**

```
editText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_back));
editText.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_back));
```

**EDIT TEXT CREATION**

```
TableRow row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.table_row_kind);
TableRow.LayoutParams rowP = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        rowP.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
editText = new EditText(this.getApplicationContext());
editText .setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
editText .setLayoutParams(rowP);
editText .setFilters(new InputFilter[]{txtFilter});
editText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_back));
```

row.xml

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/table_row_kind"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="250sp"
       android:text="Kind"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: editText.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_back)); try this @Lunchbox

Comment: I think this thread might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview/17709528#17709528

Comment: The example SO question you linked is quite rich to explain ..

Comment: @BojanJovanovic I tried your answer but still no result, instead of extending TextView, I just extended EditText. Thanks though

Comment: @Indiandroid I tried it but it did not work, see my edit

Comment: @dhams You are right, it does explain how to add a border to a view, but mine is added programmatically and does not want to work.

Comment: @Lunchbox it does not matter weather you call it from XML or from your java file .

Comment: @dhams Mine does not work. I tested it with an edit text defined in xml and it worked, then I tested it with a edit text defined in java and it does not work. I don't understand why not, hence, the question. It is a really really weird problem

Comment: @Lunchbox I have same issue. But there is problem only when you set background dynamically. If you set it in xml, it works fine. Did you got solution to that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well i also have the same issue which i solve by the following way. Its is an xml file put it on your drawable folder and set this xml into the background of that EditText

activity code:

```
EditText foo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
foo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backtext);
```

backtext.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
       <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
       <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
```

Comment: Hi, it did not work, probably because I created my edit text programmatically. See my edit

Comment: @simmant It is a good answer, but it only works for an edit text that was defined in xml. That is where my problem lies

Answer (score 3):

This Code is working for draw border to any view programmatically

```
package com.example.border;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;

public class ShapeDrawableWithoutBottom extends ShapeDrawable {
    private float mLineWidth = 1f;
    private final Paint mLinePaint;
    private int color;

    public ShapeDrawableWithoutBottom() {

        // No color specified, so call constructor with default color White
        this(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public ShapeDrawableWithoutBottom(int layoutColor) {

        // use the setter defined below, to set the main color for this drawable
        // setColor(color);
        setColor(layoutColor);
        // setup the Paint for drawing the lines
        mLinePaint = new Paint();
        mLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineWidth);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        Paint paint = getPaint();
        paint.setColor(color);

    }

    public void setLineColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setLineWidth(float lineWidth) {
        mLineWidth = lineWidth;
        mLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        // bottom black line
        // //////////////////

        mLinePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
        mLinePaint.setAlpha((int) (255 * 0.0)); // Opacity 90%
        canvas.drawLine(getBounds().left, getBounds().bottom - mLineWidth
                * 0.5f, getBounds().right, getBounds().bottom - mLineWidth
                * 0.5f, mLinePaint);

        // translucent grey rim
        // /////////////////////

        mLinePaint.setColor(color);
        mLinePaint.setAlpha((int) (255 * 0.7)); // Opacity 70%

        // top
        canvas.drawLine(getBounds().left, getBounds().top + mLineWidth * 0.5f,
                getBounds().right, getBounds().top + mLineWidth * 0.5f,
                mLinePaint);

        // left
        canvas.drawLine(getBounds().left + mLineWidth * 0.5f,
                getBounds().bottom , getBounds().left + mLineWidth
                        * 0.5f, getBounds().top + mLineWidth, mLinePaint);

        // right
        canvas.drawLine(getBounds().right - mLineWidth * 0.5f,
                getBounds().bottom , getBounds().right - mLineWidth
                        * 0.5f, getBounds().top + mLineWidth, mLinePaint);

        // top white line
        // ///////////////

        mLinePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mLinePaint.setAlpha((int) (255 * 0.5)); // Opacity 50%
        canvas.drawLine(getBounds().left + mLineWidth, getBounds().top
                + mLineWidth * 1.5f, getBounds().right - mLineWidth,
                getBounds().top + mLineWidth * 1.5f, mLinePaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks good but you don't have to set the Paint object as final since your instantiate it again in the second constructor

Answer (score 1):

Try this in this i have dynamically added edittext then set its background and it works.

```
 LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
                    EditText edit=new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    edit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc);
                    edit.setMaxWidth(100);
                    edit.setMinHeight(100);
                    edit.setText("hello");
                    layout.addView(edit);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it still doesn't work. I add my edit text to a TableRow and not a linearLayout. Added setMaxWidth and setMinHeight but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is you can make the border for the edit text. Save this into res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <gradient android:startColor="#f9f9f9"
                android:centerColor="#ffffff"
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:angle="90"/>
         <stroke  android:width="1dp" android:color="#2B547E"/>
        </shape>
         </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: What is? The xml is saved to my res/drawable

Comment: Weird, maybe try again in a couple of minutes?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
   <shape android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient android:startColor="#f9f9f9"
                android:centerColor="#ffffff"
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:angle="90"/>
   <stroke  android:width="1dp" android:color="#2B547E"/>
  </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: just copy and saved into the file_name.xml into res/drawable

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, it does work for an edit text that exists in xml, but mine does not, since it was created in java. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: what you tried ... plese write about it ... cz I hope that you are missing something

Comment: Sure, I have added borders to an edit text before, but they were defined in xml. Now I created a edit text in java and adding a border does not work. The edit text works so there are no errors, the border just does not display

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 editText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_back));
```

Instated of

```
editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_back);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, its a no go. I tried it just now again, and still the same result, just my edit text without any border.

Comment: @Lunchbox i just tried on my my galaxy note-3 . seems it works .

Comment: <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_login"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_tx_bg"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

edtLogin.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test));

Comment: I edited my answer, that is what I meant by not defining my edit text in xml, sorry if I caused any confusion