# How to create dynamic radio button checked states?

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-custom-view, radio-group

I can't figure out how to achieve this in android. I have a layout like this:

[image]

I am getting a list of images and I want them to behave like radio buttons in a radiogroup and I have implemented like that here. I can't figure out how to draw a border like this around the images when it is checked. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Shape element and dynamically put to the background of the Image View as Drawable.

[Android add border to edit text programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706307/android-add-border-to-edit-text-programmatically)