# Android ActionBar border bottom

Tags: android, android-actionbar, border, styling, underline

how can i add a border on the bottom of  my ActionBar?

Now i have:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#333333</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: add one line to top of your layout

Comment: Line as a shape? Or line on background image?

Comment: Check if this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4313329/3465623 . The point is, you can use a background like the one in this answer.

Comment: create one view in xml file with 2dp height and set background color to that.