# how add a border only on bottom of EditText?

Tags: android

I saw many related discussions but didn't find a suitable solution. What I need to do is to create a black border on  the bottom side of an EditText widget. Is that possible?

Comment: you can use image background, first thing that poped in my mind...looking for other solutions also

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I compiled this at my end :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true"><layer-list>
                <item android:bottom="-10dp" android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp"><shape>
                        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#a0e0b071" android:startColor="#a0a67637" />

                        <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#5c3708" />

                        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                    </shape></item>
            </layer-list></item>
        <item android:state_enabled="true"><layer-list>
                <item android:bottom="-10dp" android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#a0a67637" android:startColor="#a0e0b071" />

                        <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#5c3708" />

                        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                    </shape></item>
            </layer-list></item>

    </selector>
```

Comment: What is the top-level element? Could you please complete your code.

Answer (score 68):

simple create one **edittext_bottom_line.xml** file in **drawable**  folder in **res**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

To set control's single property like these:

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editTextEnterPassword"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_line"
    />
```

Comment: this doesn't work on Android version 4.1 but does work on other versions weird

Comment: EditText box/background turned black as I entered in the data.

Comment: NVM. It seems VirtualBox is the main culprit :(

Answer (score 6):

just add  **underlinebg.xml** in **res/drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/drawe_content_color_click" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and set the background where ever required. For me i got the solution like [![myoutput!!][1]][1] .I think my answer will helpful for others.

Answer (score 3):

Create a layer list with item as below

```
<item android:bottom="-1dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#111111" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create one xml file like follow:

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <size android:height="4dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/green3" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

then set this file as your background

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" `enter code here`?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="2dp" android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp" android:bottom="2dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="2dp">

            </stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```