# Add a border to the bottom of radio button text

Tags: android, radio-button, android-drawable

I am working on a android project where i need to add radio buttons as a text like following image [image]

Both text are radio buttons and clickable. To get this view i create a resources file with the name custom button

> 

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#333333" />
        <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#333333" />
        <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FF000000" />

        <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

        <padding android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

now i am setting this layout to my view as

```
 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_background"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="RadioButton1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Every thing is working fine bt m not able to set the border only to the bottom of my radio button text 
please help me to find out a way

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4313329/5778152 ?

Comment: yes nicolas cortell i did bt its not working and i am also not able to add this layer-list with my selector resource

Comment: you can also see that my third item child is exactly same