# Applying a top and bottom border to TextView using background doesn't work, but foreground does

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to set a top and bottom border to a TextView, which rests inside a ConstraintLayout, which is sitting in a CardView:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/ham_frame"
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/background"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ham_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_top_bottom"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The layer-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-2dp" android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="?attr/colorSeperator" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="-2dp" android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="?attr/colorSeperator" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now, I have gone through the questions asked about how to do that earlier, and followed multiple variations of the layer-list drawable to set as the background of the TextView, but that is simply not working for me (no borders are rendered in both a device and the editor).

Instead of that, setting the drawable as foreground just works, but the issue with that is it seems to be unsupported below API 23 (which is not acceptable).

Multiple answers here:
[Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view#:~:text=Try%20wrapping%20the%20image%20with,you%20want%20for%20your%20border.&text=You%20can%20also%20use%20a%209%2Dpath%20to%20do%20your%20job)
seem to instruct to set the drawable as background, and there doesn't seem to be anyone facing the same issue - what could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: `?attr/colorSeperator` is correctly set to `#764AFF1A`
Double-checked, neither the editor (API 26-29) nor my LG device (G7+ Pie) render the borders.

On device, with drawable set as background:
[image: Screenshot of TextView when drawable set as background, no borders visible]
With drawable set as foreground:
[image: Screenshot of TextView when drawable set as foreground, colored borders visible]

Please note the shadow-esque appearance at the top and left edges are of the container, not the TextView (which is supposed to display a slight purple-ish border).

Comment: I tried your layer-list, it can't resolve `colorSeperator`; so changed it to some custom color and the boarders are showing

Comment: Hey, which device/API are you using? I've edited the question a bit to show that it doesn't render - I'm using the exact code I pasted

Comment: Hi, I tested it on android studio emulator Pixel 2, API27...

Comment: I attempted a run in an emulated Pixel 2 API 29 now, and it also doesn't render correctly.
So it's not a device-specific issue, must be something else in my themeing.
I gave up eventually though, I'm using plain views as horizontal rules now

Comment: Can you test the TextView without the CardView?

Comment: Yes, I've done that as well, I'll attempt making a blank activity and trying the same

Comment: [this](https://imgur.com/a/V5sunSv) is how it looks like in mine

Comment: Okay, a new Empty Activity also had the same issue, so I played around with the preview settings and set the preview theme to AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (a default theme). The borders showed up then!
I'll scour through my theme attributes now, once I find what attribute I messed up, I'll post the details here. Thanks for all your help @Zain! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploring as in the discussion in the question comments with Zain, the theme (under `styles`) I was using had set the `backgroundTint` to the background color of the activity (and other components in which the TextView was lying).

So, even though the background was being set as the border drawable, it was being tinted to the color (by default) of the background of its parent, so the background was indistinguishable.

Note however that setting an explicit `backgroundTint` on the TextView *(while the one in styles existed)*, did **not** make the background visible, so the `backgroundTint` from default styling had precedence over the one set individually.
*This behavior seems to contradict [Style hierarchy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#hierarchy)
If I misinterpreted, kindly correct me*

TL;DR: If you're having a similar issue, check the backgroundTint property in `styles.xml` among the other fixes (the drawable itself).