# Android Printing Custom Layout

Tags: android, android-print-framework, android-print-manager

I have a custom layout with a border for a receipt to be printed on A5 paper. I m able to get it to work but i m facing one strange issue for the text view which has borders only on the left and bottom side. As everybody uses, i have also used layer drawable  as a background. On-screen it is displaying correctly i.e. have a border in the bottom and left. But in print out, i m getting a thin line on the top and right side of the view as well.

Adding screenshots for on-screen view and printed pdf.

[image]
[image]

How to set the text view border so i do not get thin lines on other sides where i have not set the border?

Comment: Check this our:
[Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?][1] With Love ❤️ D ❤️ [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view

Comment: Check this out : [Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?][1]. With Love ❤️ D ❤️ [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view With Love ❤️ D ❤️

Comment: @WahagWadela issue is not about adding the border. The issue is in the printed output, it is also showing a thin border on the sides, the border is not added to